# Copy text what you want

Tags: php, copy

I want a PHP code that can copy text after a selective text from string.

Like string = "hello my name is Nitesh"

Than my code can copy 6 character after "hello my name is ".

And must show only "Nitesh"

Answer (score 1):

you can use the  substring function:

```
string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )
```

in your sample:

```
substr($string, 16, 9);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
<?php
$string = "hello my name is Nitesh";
echo substr($string, 16, 9);
?>
```